# excel if and multiple and

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I need some help with an excel =if and formula

I have 4 different situations with 4 different outcomes

1. if cell N2 = 0 and A2 = "apple" then I need to print outcome AB
2. if cell N2 < 0 and A2 = "apple" then I need to print outcome CD
3. if cell N2 = 0 and A2 = "pie" then I need to print outcome EF
4. if cell N2 < 0 and A2 = "pie" then I need to print outcome GH

   ```
   =IF(AND(N2=0, A2="apple"), "AB", "CD", IF(AND(N2=0, A2="pie"), "EF", "GH"))
   ```

according to excel there are to many arguments in this formula

Comment: You have given the formula already the false value > "CD", and right after you have another parameter which doesn't excist in the `IF` statement.

Comment: hallo JvdV, thank you for your comment. What would you suggest?

Comment: Well, my suggestion would depend. Can there be any other values than `0` and `<0` in `N2` for example, and can there be other values than `apple` and `pie` in `N2`. If not, that would simplify things a lot. Otherwise you'll have to append on your `IF` statement, for example like how @SJR has done below.

Comment: Hallo JvdV , its just these values: equal to OR lower then zero and "apple" and "pie".

Comment: Posted an answer below, based on that information

Comment: Can you post a dat example? the input and the expected output. Also, make sure those zeros are numbers, not text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on:

> "*Its just these values: equal to OR lower then zero and "apple" and "pie*"

This should do:

```
=IF(N2=0,IF(A2="apple","AB","EF"),IF(A2="apple","CD","GH"))
```

Comment: almost works :) the below zero option is not involved

Comment: @Tom, it certainly is. Hence why I asked in the comment section if any other values are possible than these 4 options.

Comment: Tom - think you need to post a screenshot. Both answers work with numbers.

Comment: @JvdV: I played around with a little bit and it works fine, thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 2):

IF is of the form

> true/false statement, result if true, result if false

Your initial true/false bit is

```
AND(N2=0, A2="apple")
```

True bit

```
AB
```

False bit

```
CD
```

and that's your lot. You need to nest the next IF within the False bit.

This should work. If you have no other options, could probably be shortened. If your list gets any longer better to opt for a look-up table.

```
=IF(AND(N2=0,A2="apple"),"AB",IF(AND(N2=0,A2="pie"),"EF",IF(AND(N2<0,A2="apple"),"CD",IF(AND(N2<0,A2="pie"),"GH","???"))))
```

Comment: Hello SJR, just tried it, didn't work unfortunately for 100% (all results became "???"). But the good news is that it didn't throw any errors.

Comment: Works for me... Trailing spaces?

Comment: It absolutely worked :). I got a feeling OP's `0` and `<0` might be text.